# ¿Tamaño de String maximo del atributo de un elemento HTML?

Tags: javascript, html5, web-components

cómo están, estoy trabajando con la API de custom elements y usualmente manejo mucho los elementos HTML dentro del componente, así como si fuera react pero más nativo del HTML

Necesito traerme unas imágenes con cada click a un elemento, yo la pido del servidor, pero después sería bueno guardarla en cache para no tener que volver a llamar al servidor.

Es ahí donde pensé, los atributos de un elemento HTML son String pero, tienen tamaño máximo? Podría meter un String de base64 de tamaños superiores a 1MB e inferiores a 10 MB ?

Cualquiera que conteste está pregunta está perfecto, podemos conversar acerca de esto sin problemas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML 5

A diferencia de HTML4, como [las especificaciones](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) dicen, "Esta versión de HTML regresa a una base no SGML."

Más adelante, cuando describe cómo procesar HTML5, el siguiente extracto aparece:

> El algoritmo descrito a continuación, **no establece límite alguno** sobre el tamaño  del árbol DOM generado, ni **sobre el tamaño** de los nombres de las etiquetas, nombres de atributos, **sus valores**, nodos de texto, etc. Aunque se alienta a los implementadores a evitar límites arbitrarios, se reconocen preocupaciones en la práctica que obligarán a los agentes de usuario a imponer límites de tamaño.

(Traducción)

Fuente: Stackoverflow en inglés: [Is there a limit to the length of HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes)

Comment: Perfecta respuesta, nada mas claro que esto. Capaz esto le interese a alguien: Leí en un libro de microprocesadores que HTML y JavaScript (web) y en general, la world wide web nació con interpretadores Java Virtual Machine escritos en C, no confirmo que sea exactamente como lo estoy diciendo. Pero me ayuda a pensar la idea en que realmente cada elemento HTML5 no es mas que una clase con sus atributos y métodos, porque en el fondo así se conforma toda la estructura que corre sobre la web, capaz este cerca de lo cierto o no, pero siempre es bueno hablarlo porque no hay mucha inf en español